# Lilypond variables in \relative score

Tags: lilypond

I've been avoiding using variables in Lilypond as the pieces I've been scoring have been short but I'm now beginning to use bars (phrases?) repeatedly.

What is the best approach to the problem of having a variable repeat but in a \relative context which results in the variable not being scored in the correct octave (as it deduces position from the prior notes)?

See below as an example, where the `bebtuplet` variable is produced at a different octave on second use.

```
\version "2.23"

global = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
  \tempo 4 = 60
}

bebtuplet = {
    <b e b'>2~ <b e b'>8 a' e c  | << { e1 } \\ { \tuplet 3/2 {b16 c b} a8~ a2. }  >>
}

rh =  {
  \relative c'' {

    g8 g g g << { d'4.( c8) } \\ { f,2 } >> | \bebtuplet |  \break

    << { e2 <d~ f>4 <d e>4 } >> | \bebtuplet | \break
  }
}

\score {
   \context PianoStaff <<
   \context Staff = "rh" <<
     \global
     \clef "treble"
     \rh
   >>
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

[image: result of posted code: repeated material in two different octaves]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two (related) options.

1. Enclose the repeated block within its own `\relative` block.

```
bebtuplet = { \relative c'' {
    <b e b'>2~ <b e b'>8 a' e c  | << { e1 } \\ { \tuplet 3/2 {b16 c b} a8~ a2. }  >>
}}
```

[image: Result of above code inserted into OP code]

2. You could also use `\fixed` in a similar way. See the LilyPond manual for [Absolute octave entry](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation-big-page.html#absolute-octave-entry).

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge. You ask for "the best approach". A better approach than using `\relative` is not using it. When you specify each note's pitch absolutely, it's much easier for you to be sure that each note is in the octave you intend. If you find that that means typing more ticks than you like to, use `\transpose`.

Your example indicates that you'd find `\transpose` useful anyway.